# tensorflow sequential model outputting nan

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

Why is my code outputting nan? I'm using a sequential model with a 30x1 input vector and a single value output. I'm using tensorflow and python. This is one of my firs

```
While True:

 # Define a simple sequential model
 def create_model():
   model = tf.keras.Sequential([
     keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu',input_shape=(30,)),
     keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu'),
     keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='relu'),
     keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
   ])

   model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                 loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                 metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

   return model

 # Create a basic model instance
 model = create_model()

 # Display the model's architecture
 model.summary()

 train_labels=[1]
 test_labels=[1]

 train_images= [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]]
 test_images=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]]

 model.fit(train_images, 
           train_labels,  
           epochs=10,
           validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
           verbose=1)  
            
 print('predicted:',model.predict(train_images))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. It expects labels to be integers starting from 0. So, you have only one label `1`, but it means you have at least two categories - 0 and 1. So you need at least two neurons in the last layer:

```
keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

( If your goal is classification, you should maybe consider to use softmax instead of sigmoid, without `from_logits=True` )

Comment: Using sigmoid with two neurons is equivalent to three classes. One class represents weights set to 0. Softmax, otoh, uses the number of neurons as the number of classes (which, by extension, so does sigmoid). You can use two neurons with sigmoid in a two-class model, one class will be ignored. The extra neuron also increases resources

Comment: Also, the keras backend actually ignores the user-set activation function whenever `from_logits=True` is used with SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. Keras will automagically override the activation function with `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. OP needs to change the loss function to BinaryCrossEntropy for one neuron and remove the `from_logits` call (or set it to False, the default for CrossEntropy) if they want to continue with sigmoid. If they want softmax for two classes, just change the output neuron number to 2.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong loss function for those labels. You need to use `BinaryCrossentropy`.

Change:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                 loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                 metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
```

To:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                 loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy,
                 metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
```